# Call a ruby script from python, and return response

Tags: python, ruby, python-2.7

I am using python, and I want to call a Ruby function (i.e. in a similar manner to how i would call a python function), specifying function arguments, and then get back a returned value.

I have been searching around, and can see how to run ruby code e.g. using os.system, however can't seem to either:

1. call a specific function within the Ruby code, passing variables
2. Return the result of the function to Python.

e.g. I am looking to be able to do something similar to:

```
 desired_response = ruby_function(variables)
```

where ruby_function is within a file called ruby_file, and the response is the result of running that function.

Comment: for reference, while there may have been more elegant ways of doing this, i ended up saving the function variables in a text file, calling the ruby file, which extracted the variables from the text file, and then saved it's output in another text file, which Python read back in.

Comment: Some thoughts: make the ruby script itself return the value and then use `subprocess.check_output`; wrap the ruby function in a microservice using sinatra; use JRuby and jython together (not so sure about this one...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your output from ruby program but with  `os.startfile()`you can run your ruby script.

Comment: My output is a string, and I am looking to get that string back into python

Comment: also this link in stackoverflow: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679501/calling-python-from-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more recent solution that i found and seems a lot smoother than having a third party tool to invoke this.

You can simply use the Python subprocess.
I ended up using it this way:

import subprocess
response = subprocess.run([f"{os.environ['YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH']}", first_variable_to_pass_to_script, second_variable])

Hope this helps!

###OLD ANSWER:
I found this article to be helpful!
[http://sweetme.at/2014/03/14/a-simple-approach-to-execute-ruby-scripts-with-python/#:~:text=Execute%20the%20Ruby%20File%20from%20Naked.toolshed.shell%20import%20execute_rb,the%20Ruby%20code%20to%20the%20Python%20calling%20code](http://sweetme.at/2014/03/14/a-simple-approach-to-execute-ruby-scripts-with-python/#:%7E:text=Execute%20the%20Ruby%20File%20from%20Naked.toolshed.shell%20import%20execute_rb,the%20Ruby%20code%20to%20the%20Python%20calling%20code).

You might need to use:

from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_rb
success = execute_rb('testscript.rb')

to be able to handle your standard I/O error in Python rather than Ruby.

Original documentation: https://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html